# ajax add to cart on product list

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, ajaxaddtocart

I want a trick to add product to cart whitout reloading page, I'm not looking for a paid extension , just code ajax to make product added to cart on my product list.
thank you

Comment: there are lot of free extensions for magento 1 you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You have to search on Google and you will find a lot of free examples.

You can look on this links:

For product page:
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/04/magento-add-product-to-cart-ajax/

For category page:
http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/23/ajax-based-product-add-to-cart-from-category-page/

And there are so many examples, you only have to search for it.

Comment: I've already try some but it doesn't work on magento 1.9